# Getting error in HtmlHelper/Razor in asp.net mvc-5

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I have created one cshtml file. When I run/build the solution in visual studio the solution builds fine and even the functionality wise (as far as I can tell) everything seems to be working but I see some errors in Visual Studio error window. Can someone guide me why I see those errors.

```
@if (Utils.IsCC)
{
    <div class="CC">
        <div class="form">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreditDetails.CreditCard, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
             // Red squiggly comes in the entire line above
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Error :**

> The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, 
>       System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary)' 
>       cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `model.CreditDetails.CreditCard` has a type that is hard to reconize for MVC.

Try turning it into a normal type, OR specify the type you should use directly.

```
@Html.LabelFor<string>(model => model.CreditDetails.CreditCard, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
```

or

```
@Html.LabelFor<ComplexObject>(model => model.CreditDetails.CreditCard, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
```

That is what the error is trying to tell you, but i don't know if there is a better/perfect solution for this.